# How to prevent user from proceeding without entering value in edittext in android app?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to android and programming. I am writing an app for calculating BMI. It works fine but there is a problem. The basic structure is:
Weight:  "Edittext"
Height:  "Edittext"

Reset     Calculate   <--- buttons

The app hangs whenever the user presses calculate button without entering a value (Height or weight). thats happening because a mathematical calculation is taking place without any values. how can i prevent the calculation from taking place when there are no values?????

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick function for the calculate button, check to see if the values make sense. If they don't, then don't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

prior to any operation check for null values .

```
onCkick(View V)
{
if(editWeight.getText() != null or editHeight.getText() != null)
{
//do operation
}
}
```

Comment: i tried using this method but it does not work. Eclipse says onClick(View V) is an error.

Comment: vivek please go through documents first . seems you are just starting to code in android . onClick() is override method of clickListener